# How to automatically delete a file at a specific time after closing it?

Tags: files

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I am here to know: is there any way to limit the life time of a file?

I mean, for example, I have created a file that has to be automatically deleted 10 minutes after I close it. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished using `inotifywait` from `inotify-tools` package (it's not installed by default):

```
inotifywait -e close /path/to/file && sleep 600 && rm /path/to/file
```

This will set up a watch on `/path/to/file` and wait for it to be closed. Then after 10 minutes (600 seconds) the file will be removed.

Here's a script to make things easier:

`selfdestroy.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# != 2 ]; then
        echo "$0 <file> <time>"
        exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
        echo "File $1 not found."
        exit 1
fi

if (( $2 < 1 )); then
        echo "Time must be > 0."
fi

(inotifywait -e close $1
sleep $2
rm $1) 2>1 >/dev/null &
```

Call the script like this: `selfdestroy.sh /path/to/file 600`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to write a script to perform this.

Using the commands

- **access** (read the file's contents) - `atime`
- **change** the status (modify the file or its attributes) - `ctime`
- **modify** (change the file's contents) - `mtime`
- `cron`
- `find`

**Sample Script to remove the '.bak' file**

> ```
>  #!/bin/bash
>   find <location> -mtime <value> -type f -name "*.bak" -exec rm -f {} \;
> ```

Change the permission of the script (execute)

add the script to `cron` and make it run when needed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer +1 :) , but Eric gave me as exactly i need. :D

Comment: yes @EricCarvalho answer must perfectly solve your issue.